# .NET: When are large heap objects garbage collected?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I have a program that requests HTML from a webservice, modifies the HTML to highlight search terms and then displays the HTML in a WebBrowser component. Sometimes the HTML I receive will be quite large causing my "Mem Usage" and "VM Size", as displayed in task manager, to blow up to ~600 Meg. If I do not perform any other operation it seems my app will consume these memory resources indefinitely. If I do a forced GC I can get these resources released but am loathe to do that since I don't really understand why the framework isn't releasing the resources when they are no longer referenced.

I have two questions:

1. Are "Mem Usage" and "VM Size" dependable metrics for what my program is consuming?
2. If there are multiple .Net apps running on the same machine will the memory needs of one .Net app cause .Net to free resources from the other .Net applications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The garbage collector is a heavy operation so it gets done only when the system decides it's necessary (ie there's a memory pressure). The fact that 600MB are "blown up" has no impact as long as the system does not need them for something else.

Comment: The best answer possible, especially considering that Microsoft is not 100% forthcoming with internal GC logic as well as the different GC flavors that are possible.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to coffee_machine' answer: The Large Object Heap is only collected when a full collection is performed. This only happens if the system absolutely needs the resources for something else.

About your seconds question: Of course, if one .NET program needs memory and the runtime request that memory from the operating system, there is memory pressure just like a native program would have requested the memory and the .NET runtime will perform a garbage collection.